# Migrate Data from TFS to New Site Collection

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, migrate

Is it possible to easily migrate data from and SharePoint TFS Site to a new SharePoint Site Collection (both are 2010 I believe)?

Some of the data is just files that if I need to I can download a copy and re-upload it to the new site. This wouldn't be ideal because there are about 50 of them them but it can be done. However, I have no idea how to do this with the other important information that needs to be migrated. The rest of the important information isn't really in a file form, they may be called Lists but I'm not sure[image] so I've attached a screenshot. I'm an intern so I'm not sure what information might be confidential or anything like that so I just blacked out most of the non-essential information in the screenshot. Many of these "Lists" will have emails from outlook attached that will need to stay with the rest of the list.

I imagine the solution won't be simple but if you have any insights I would great appreciate them.

Comment: I figured out I can open the library in explorer to download all of the files at once. If I can't find an equally fast way to upload them I'll just do it one at a time. However, I still have no idea how to download copies of the items I mentioned above which the screenshot is an example of. Also, there are 600 of those so I will definitely need a fairly quick way of doing it.

Comment: did you try to backup restore method or for list save as template?

Comment: I found instructions for the template method but I don't have the right access on the old SP site so I haven't been able to try that yet. I'm not sure what the back-up restore method is. I'm really very new to SP. However, I did export the entire list to a spreadsheet then upon creating a new list I had the option to create the list from a spreadsheet. So that actually got me everything I needed EXCEPT the attachments associated with each list item from the original site. Do you know if either the back-up restore method or save as template will allow me to copy the attachments as well?

Comment: i think you need site collection admin rights or full control on the list at least

Comment: Yes attachment will copied with template( if use include content option).

Comment: Thanks, on a side note could you tell me what's wrong with saying "thanks in advance" at the end of my post?

Comment: I learnt, no need to say Thanks...Because when you asked the question, Question itself say thanks to all forum member...Because you trust on us and ask the questions.

Comment: did you try and things works for you

Comment: I'm still waiting for access to the old site. I requested access when prompted by SharePoint and a day later a friend came over and said that he is the one who received the request but he doesn't know how to approve it and doesn't even have access to view the list himself, so we don't know why he received the request. He requested access to see who responds to him. In the meantime I submitted a Remedy Ticket, usually they're pretty quick but I still haven't heard anything.

Comment: Correction: I'm not waiting for access to the old site, I'm waiting for the proper access so that I can save the list as a template. I have access to the site and the list but for some reason I can't save the list as a template.

Comment: So, no-one knows who the site/list owner is or how to grant me access. I have no idea how this happens but it did, so does anyone have any suggestions as to how else I could transfer this list and attachments? I mean of course I could transfer the list then manually transfer the attachments BUT there are 1400 list items to go through and I only have about 5 days left before my internship is over. Failing to get this list and attachments transferred over shouldn't reflect negatively on me since I requested the extra work and it's essentially out of my hands but I would like to complete it.